# Flutter existing project to WebApp + Firebase (Firestore + Hosting)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I have an existing Flutter app (runs correctly on Android/IOS) using Firestore.

**GOAL:**

1. I'd like to first have it support web
2. I'd like to host it on Firebase hosting

**Results so far:**

1. When running in local, blank page
2. When deploying to firebase, doesn't even seem to run index.html

**What I tried**

1. According to [this](https://medium.com/flutter/must-try-use-firebase-to-host-your-flutter-app-on-the-web-852ee533a469) tutorial :

   a) Added a Web App on my firebase project

   b) `npm install -g firebase-tools`

   c) `firebase login`

   d) `firebase init`

   ==> I select Firestore and Hosting

   ==> Use existing project, select my project

   ==> use all defaut setup (except build/web folder for public directory)

   e) `flutter channel dev
   flutter upgrade
   flutter config --enable-web`

   f) `flutter create .`

   g) `flutter build web`

   h) I then copy all the content from build/web to /web folder, add the CDN from firebase at the bottom of the body, then call Firebase JS SDKs the following way :

**ERRORS**

I get this error when running locally on chrome:

```
(index):53 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
```

As for using `firebase deploy`, the page says I successfully set up hosting but does not show index.html

For reference :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

    <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="kidz_happy_pawn">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

    <title>kidz_happy_pawn</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/resources/tutorial/css/example.css'>
</head>
<body>

<div id="message">
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <h1>Firebase Hosting Setup Complete</h1>
    <p>You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go
        build something extraordinary!</p>
</div>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxx-from-firebase",
    authDomain: "xxx-from-firebase",
    databaseURL: "xxx-from-firebase",
    projectId: "xxx-from-firebase",
    storageBucket: "xxx-from-firebase",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx-from-firebase",
    appId: "xxx-from-firebase",
    measurementId: "xxx-from-firebase"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();

</script>

<script>

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }

</script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on how you have set up your firebase apis.from [flutter fire](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_web) here is how you should set it up.
In your app directory, edit web/index.html to add the following:
`

```
<body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
     <!-- ADD THIS BEFORE YOUR main.dart.js SCRIPT -->
```

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "[YOUR_PROJECT].firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://[YOUR_PROJECT].firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "[YOUR_PROJECT]",
  storageBucket: "[YOUR_PROJECT].appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "1:...:web:",
  measurementId: ""
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

`

Comment: I did this exactly and I'm getting the same error : Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined. I added index.html for reference.

Comment: I'm a bit confused why but it seems to work now (with previous posted code). Thanks